# Sending Array List using Dagger 2

Tags: android, design-patterns, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm new to dependency injection and Dagger 2 library for android.

First, is it a good practice to use dagger 2 to set a list for my custom adapter as I have done below.

Say i have this:

```
    package com.example.a3adel.vogellaexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.inject.Inject;


public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    @Inject
    ArrayList<String> listArray;
    public ListAdapter(Activity context){
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) context.getApplication();

        app.getComponent().inject(this);

        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,parent,false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

and i initialize the arraylist in the main activity like this:

```
 @Provides
    @Singleton
    ArrayList<String> getList() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("test");
        list.add("test2");
        list.add("test3");
        return list;
    }
```

I have my component like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MainActivity.class})
public interface DiComponent {
    void inject(ListAdapter adapter);

}
```

Is this good practice? Is there a better way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think injecting data to android provider isn't good responsibility of DI.

If you have static array you can simpler use string array from resources https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray.
If array generated in runtime may be better way is define some provider class which contain logic of this array generation an inject them.

Optionally you may use @Qualifier http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html to separate providers with same signature but different meaning.